# ear file generated by maven doesn't contain the classes from the project

Tags: java, maven, ear

I have a simple java project with my only source file being in `projectName/src/main/java/Example.java` . In my `pom.xml` I have `<packaging>ear</packaging>` added.

After using Maven's install I can find an `.ear` file in my `target` folder.

Problem is, if I open it using 7zip, there are only `.jar` files associated with my other dependencies, and a `META-INF` folder with additional folders which contains `pom.xml` and `pom.properties` files but nothing about my `Example` class where I look for.

Have I missed anything?

Is there any way to package a maven project into an `.ear` file?

Comment: An EAR modules does not contain code and will not compile the code nor package the code. If you have code you should have a separate WAR/EJB/JAR module....

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge but does that mean having a JAR module in my project with the code and `mvn clean install` the parent project will translate into having an `.ear` file with the `.jar` containing the classes inside it? If not is there any way I can get  the desired classes in my `.ear` file at all?

Comment: I'm asking because I found a sample ear file provided [here](https://developers.redhat.com/products/rhamt/hello-world/) which contains inside it a `.jar` with the classes from the project. This is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Best is to create a multi module build which comprises of a parent with two childs one the jar module and one the ear module..The ear mudule will have a dependency on the jar module (Example: https://github.com/khmarbaise/javaee)...